# How do I add a git submodule that has no master branch?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have two git repositories: `A` and `B`. I want to make `B` a submodule of `A`. `B` has no `master` branch.

I ran the following command from `A`'s repository root:

```
git submodule add git@git.example.com:B lib/B
```

Which yields the following output:

```
Cloning into 'lib/B'...
remote: Counting objects: 156, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (151/151), done.
remote: Total 156 (delta 45), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (156/156), 109.80 KiB | 140 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (45/45), done.
fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born
Unable to checkout submodule 'lib/B'
```

My `.gitmodules` file has no entry for `B`, but `.git/modules/lib/B` exists. If I `cd lib/B`, I can `git checkout develop` (`B`'s only branch), but git sees any files under `lib/B` as part of `A`.

Is there any way to tell git to add a submodule that has no `master` branch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will add the branch you specify as a submodule

```
git submodule add -b <branch> ...
```

You can find this information by doing `git submodule -h` or `man git-submodule`

Link to [man page for git submodule](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html)